# Restore Errors on Sharepoint

Tags: user-profile-service, backup, excel-services, restore

I got up backup a server. And I want to restore the backup to nother server. But  I got this error and my restore job is failed.

> Object Excel Service Application failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
>       SPException: The specified component exists. You must specify a name that does not exist.
>
> User Profile Service  Error 12/8/2014 8:20 AM Object User Profile Service failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
>       SPException: The specified component exists. You must specify a name that does not exist.
>
> http  Completed 12/8/2014 8:20 AM
>   Profile DB  Error 12/8/2014 8:20 AM 
>   Object Profile DB failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
>       SPException: The specified component exists. You must specify a name that does not exist.
>
> Sync DB  Error 12/8/2014 8:20 AM Object Sync DB failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
>       SPException: The specified component exists. You must specify a name that does not exist.
>
> Social DB  Error 12/8/2014 8:20 AM Object Social DB failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
>       SPException: The specified component exists. You must specify a name that does not exist.

How can I solved those? I looked logs it says "SPException: The specified component exists. You must specify a name that does not exist."

Also, I can delete excel service on "Manage Service Applications on Central Adminstration" but I can't delete User Profile Service. I got this error.
[image]

Comment: For the user profile, see if this can help you out. The 3 databases are releated to the UPS so i think it can help. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2762522

Comment: @user19952 I read the document.it's saying close the user profile server during the restore process. I tried this but my restore process failed again. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It does not say close/pause the user profile, more to stop all the timer jobs that can update the user profile, so you need to find out all of timerjobs that are related to the UPS and pause/stop them while trying to do the restore.

Comment: I turn off all timerjob and I tried restore again, but I got same error about "WSS_Content" @user19952